# How do i interface with Smartthings from a capsule?

Tags: bixby

I know how to create Bixby capsules and have seen the viv library, but see no way to interface with Smartthings

Looked through Bixby  developer docs

Cant show any

Comment: I'm guessing it's not going to be native inside Bixby and you'd have to use the smartthings rest api. https://smartthings.developer.samsung.com/docs/api-ref/st-api.html#

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Bixby invoke an existing SmartThings automation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57102858/can-bixby-invoke-an-existing-smartthings-automation)