# Can Bixby invoke an existing SmartThings automation?

Tags: automation, bixby, smartthings

Can't find any documentation on the Bixby verbal command to invoke an existing SmartThings automation

I know how to speak a Bixby command to CREATE  a SmartThings automation to run at a later time, but not to invoke one that is already created

none

I expect it should be able to do this. Also, is it possible for Bixby  to create an automation that runs everyday, not just ONCE

...update... I found that this can be done by including the phrase "every day" in the command. e.g. :"Hi Bixby, turn off the entry light every day at 7:00AM"

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking into the SmartThings documentation for help with integration (https://smartthings.developer.samsung.com/).